# Mockito Inline Mock Maker - throws Exception - Argument passed to when() is not a mock

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I wanted to mock static methods, hence used dependency "mockito-inline" 3.8 version instead of "mockito-core"

The static method mocks work fine but my old tests that mock interfaces fail with the below error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

Reverting to using mockito-core solves the issue but then I would not be able to mock static methods

Is there any way we can choose different mockito engines (Subclass/Inline) for each class?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to mock static methods and you cannot use `mockito-inline` you could do something like this with `mockito-core`:

```java
public class MockitoUtil {
    
    public static <T, S> void mockStaticMethod(Class<T> classToMock, String nameOfMethodToMock, S result) {
        MockCreationSettings<T> settings = mock(MockCreationSettings.class);
        when(settings.isSerializable()).thenReturn(true);
        
        MockHandler<T> handler = new MockHandler<>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public Object handle(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
                String invokedMethodName = invocation.getMethod().getName();
                if(!invokedMethodName.equals(nameOfMethodToMock)){
                    String message = "called %s on class %s, but only %s was implemented";
                    throw new Exception(String.format(message, invokedMethodName, classToMock.getName(), nameOfMethodToMock));
                }
                return result;
            }
            @Override
            public MockCreationSettings<T> getMockSettings() { return null; }
            @Override
            public InvocationContainer getInvocationContainer() { return null; }
        };
        
        MockMaker.StaticMockControl<T> classToMockControl = Mockito
                    .framework()
                    .getPlugins()
                    .getInlineMockMaker()
                    .createStaticMock(classToMock, settings, handler);
        
        classToMockControl.enable();
    }
    
}
```

**N.B.** you should call `classToMockControl.disable()` after the static method invocation if you'd like to mock static methods of other classes in the same test

Answer (score 0):

MockResolver fixed the issue as described in https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1980